# Unable to type in a react native text field

Tags: react-native

I m trying to create a basic login page but I'm not able to write anything in text field. Here is a file login.js. How can I solve this? I'm a beginner in react-native.

```
import React ,{Component} from 'react';
import {View ,Text,ImageBackground,TouchableOpacity,TextInput} from 'react-native';
    export default class Login extends Component
    {
      constructor(props)
      {
        super(props)
        this.state={
          username:"",
          password:""
        }
      }
      render()
      {
        return(
          <ImageBackground source={require('./background2.png')} 
                style={{height:'100%', width:'100%'}} >
    
          <View style={{width:'100%',height:'100%',alignSelf:'center'
          ,justifyContent:'center',alignContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
<TextInput placeholder={"Enter the user Name"}
onChangeText={(value)=>this.setState({username:value})}
style={{height:42,width:'80%',borderBottomWidth:1}}>
</TextInput>
<TextInput placeholder={"Enter the password"}
 onChangeText={(value)=>this.setState({password:value})}
 style={{height:42,width:'80%',borderBottomWidth:1,marginTop:'5%'}}>
 </TextInput>
 <View style={{marginTop:'5%',width:'80%'}}>
 <TouchableOpacity style={{borderWidth:1,height:42,width:'80%'
  ,justifyContent:"center",alignItems:'center',borderRadius:40,
 backgroundColor:'black',alignSelf:'center',textAlign:'center'}}>
<Text style={{color:'white'}}>Login</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
</View>
</View>
</ImageBackground>
          
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to adding value props to TextInput component. Just pass the state value that you changing onChangeText event. Something like <TextInput value={this.state.password} onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({password : value})}/>.

Comment: Sorry brother but i don't understand it.

Comment: Yeh. I added some code but that has not been included. Now have a look.

Comment: Not working bro,actually i m using physical emulator and whenever i run this application i m not getting cursor in textbox , can't even write anything.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following snack.

https://snack.expo.io/HMDWDe!eL

It is working!!

Following is the code...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  ImageBackground,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';
export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={require('./background2.jpg')}
        style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>
        <View
          style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            alignSelf: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder={'Enter the user Name'}
            onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({ username: value })}
            style={{
              height: 42,
              width: '80%',
              borderBottomWidth: 1,
            }}></TextInput>
          <TextInput
            placeholder={'Enter the password'}
            onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({ password: value })}
            style={{
              height: 42,
              width: '80%',
              borderBottomWidth: 1,
              marginTop: '5%',
            }}></TextInput>
          <View style={{ marginTop: '5%', width: '80%' }}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{
                borderWidth: 1,
                height: 42,
                width: '80%',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                borderRadius: 40,
                backgroundColor: 'black',
                alignSelf: 'center',
                textAlign: 'center',
              }}>
              <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
```